# Can the strength of photon torpedoes be adjusted?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager, star-trek-tos

The strength of a phaser blast can be adjusted, at least on the Enterprise-D (and probably the other ships with which we're familiar). In "Galaxy's Child," for example, the space entity is shot with a phaser beam that is only at 3% strength. In "The Ultimate Computer," phasers are initially at low intensity during the training exercise.

Can the strength of the photon torpedoes also be adjusted?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.  Data does just that while he is in command of the *Sutherland* in the TNG episode [Redemption, Part II](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/201.htm).  Data is part of a sensor net blockade tasked with preventing cloaked Romulan Warbirds from sneaking supplies to the Duras faction in the Klingon civil war.   The Romulans fire a massive tachyon burst to disable the sensor net long enough to slip past the blockade, but Data figures out a way to expose them, using torpedoes set to a low-power yield that will not damage them, but will expose their presence.

> DATA: Overlay display with tachyon emissions. Highlight any tachyon signatures which show subspace inertial displacement. Concentrate a
> sensor sweep in that area.
>
> (four targets emerge)
>
> HOBSON: Sir, this is pointless. Those readings could be anything.
> There's no way for us to be sure the Romulans are out there.
>
> DATA: Reconfigure photon torpedo warhead yields. Set for high energy
> burst level six.
>
> HOBSON: Level six? But that won't even
>
> DATA: Do it!

Comment: In ST:TNG, episode "Nth Degree", the order is given "photon torpedoes, maximum yield!"  I infer from "maximum yield" that lesser yields are therefore possible.